# CLLocationManager:didDetermineState:forRegion not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, core-location

I'm implementing iOS7 app using google maps SDK for iOS & region monitoring of CoreLocation framework. After registering monitoring region, calling requestStateForRegion method but I have no reaction on didDetermineState:forRegion method on device(iOS7.0.4, iPhone5S).

it can receive didUpdateLocation method, so I think delegation process is working fine. On simulator, didDetermineState:forRegion method called properly.

What should I do to fix this problem?
initialization code is as follows.

Any advice appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if (locManager == nil ) {
        locManager = [CLLocationManager new];
    }
    locManager.delegate = self;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D targetCenter;
    targetCenter.latitude = LATITUDE_CENTER;
    targetCenter.longitude = LONGITUDE_CENTER;
    CLLocationDegrees radius = TARGET_RADIUS;
    if ( locManager.maximumRegionMonitoringDistance < TARGET_RADIUS ){
        radius = locManager.maximumRegionMonitoringDistance;
    }
    self.targetRegion = [[CLCircularRegion alloc]
                     initWithCenter:targetCenter
                     radius:radius
                     identifier:@"TargetRegion"];

    BOOL monitoringAvailability = [CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[self.targetRegion class]];
    if( monitoringAvailability ) {
        if( [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized ) {
            [locManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.targetRegion];
        }
    }

    [locManager requestStateForRegion:self.targetRegion];  
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    if (state == CLRegionStateInside){
        NSLog(@"is in target region");
        self.isInTargetRegion = YES;
    }else{
        NSLog(@"is out of target region");
        self.isInTargetRegion = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if startMonitoringForRegion failed, so I checked  locManager.monitoredRegions then I found properly started monitoring.

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer myself.

on the iPhone device, 
Settings -> General -> Background App Refresh
enable background app refresh of the app, then called didDetermineState properly.

Comment: This also causes issues with CLBeaconRegion. `isMonitoringAvailableForClass:` returns `YES` even thought BackgroundAppRefresh is off. But the Apple's *Location and Maps Programming Guide* indicates it should return `NO` in this situation.

Comment: @Tobias, the behavior of `isMonitoringAvailableForClass:` is correct. The `isMonitoringAvailableForClass:` method tells you whether the underlying **hardware** supports region monitoring for the specified class at all. It has nothing to do with background app refresh.

Comment: @reecon - Thanks for the info. Just reread the Documentation and it does clearly say **hardware**. It also says that I can check for background refresh status by calling `[UIApplication backgroundRefreshStatus]`. I should have RTFM closely. I thought the bullet points were connected to `isMonitoringAvailableForClass:` method.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 8, you need to prompt for `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways` using `[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]`. You will also need to have a `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` entry in your Info.plist file.

Answer (score 0):

Implement this callback

```
(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error
```